Why can't I configure aggrid column with URL in streamlit?
I'm trying to customize some grid options and encountering an attribute error when attempting to set a column as a URL link. I'm using streamlit 1.38.0 and streamlit-aggrid 1.0.5.
import streamlit as st
from st_aggrid import GridOptionsBuilder, AgGrid, GridUpdateMode, JsCode

gob = GridOptionsBuilder.from_dataframe(filtered)
for column in filtered.columns:
gob.configure_column(column, filter=True)

cell_renderer =  JsCode("""
function(params) {return `<a href=${params.value} target="_blank">${params.value}</a>`}
""")
gob.configure_column("link",
headerName="Link",
cellRenderer=cell_renderer)
gridOptions = gob.build()

AgGrid(filtered, gridOptions=gridOptions, update_mode=GridUpdateMode.MODEL_CHANGED)

I get AttributeError: module 'streamlit.components.v1' has no attribute 'components'
I think the problem could be solved using compatible library versions, but I need to use the latest streamlit version

You need to add allow_unsafe_jscode=True to your Aggrid options.
AgGrid(filtered, gridOptions=gridOptions, update_mode=GridUpdateMode.MODEL_CHANGED, allow_unsafe_jscode=True)

source: https://github.com/streamlit/streamlit/issues/8644#issuecomment-2198282602
For more information on the option, you can look at the documentation in streamlit aggrid:
    allow_unsafe_jscode : bool, optional
        Allows jsCode to be injected in gridOptions.
        Defaults to False.

source: https://github.com/PablocFonseca/streamlit-aggrid/blob/1b31edc513aa41414a2341642559bbfe232b158f/st_aggrid/__init__.py#L203
